# laravel blade file displaying blank screen

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a blade.php file that I am able to go to in my web browser. However, when I go to the file in my web browser I find that the screen is blank, despite the fact that the blade.php file should be displaying text.

Here is the blade.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-family: 'Lato';
        }

        .container {
            text-align: center;
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .content {
            text-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 96px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title"> another test </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I am able to go the pg in the browser I don't think it is an error with the controller or the routes.php file. I have another blade.php file that has the same code and does display something when I go into it on a web browser.

Here is the file path for the blade.php file that isn't working.
Laravel/resources/views/pages/manualsignup.blade.php

Here is the file path for the blade.php file that is working 
Laravel/resources/views/pages/test.blade.php

I have tried doing php artisan view:clear but it hasn't fixed the problem.

I am not getting any error, so to the best of my understanding the logs file won't have anything for this situation. Here are a few of the most recent logs in the log files, but I don't think they are relevant here, I think they are from previous errors that I fixed.

[2016-02-04 16:39:29] local.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: View [about] not found. in /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php:137
Stack trace:

```
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php(79): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->findInPaths('about', Array)
 #1 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php(151): Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder->find('about')

#2 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(737): Illuminate\View\Factory->make('about', Array, Array)
 #3 /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/app/Http/routes.php(21): view('about')
 #4 [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->{closure}()
```

Comment: Your logs will tell you what the error is. Have you checked them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after spending a few hours on this I realized that I didn't have return view("pages.filename") in my controller. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

**Logs**

Laravel provides logs, be sure of your version of Laravel to have the right location.

Laravel 5 `storage/logs`

Laravel 4 `app/storage/logs`

These files are very helpfully, try to find there any information about the blade render.

**Permissions**

Otherwise you can try to set the right permissions to the folder storage, when i say right permissions i mean to write permissions for your current user. This would to the trick.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Comment: I went into my Laravel project directory and tried the terminal command. It didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: Any info in the logs files ? You can try to call a undefined variable on purpose, whit this you be sure that Laravel write in the logs file. If after you to that, your logs folder still is empty, is a permission problem.

Comment: I don't have anything in my logs file for this problem so it probably is a permission problem. However,  sudo chmod -R 777 storage/ did not fix it. If you have any other suggestions please let me know

Comment: Ok, to be sure of your storage permission folder, you can paste the result of this command: ls -ld storage/ and ls -ld storage/logs.

Comment: Great, i'm happy that your find the error, regards.